# By taking answers modulo $m$, show that $Z_m$ has no divisors of zero iff $m$ is prime

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For a positive integer $m$, let

$Z_m$ = {$0,1,...,m-1$}

$+: Z_m * Z_m \rightarrow Z_m$

Mult: $Z_m * Z_m \rightarrow Z_m$

by taking answers modulo $m$ (e.g. $Z_6$ = {$0,1,2,3,4,5$} and $(3)(5)$ = $15$ modulo $6 = 3$) Show that $Z_m$ has no divisors of zero $\Longleftrightarrow$ $m$ is a prime.

---

I'm guess I'm getting confused about the zero divisor part. I'm unsure how to approach this problem.

Comment: What are *answers* modulo $m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First suppose that $m$ is prime.  Then
$$\eqalign{\def\Z{{\Bbb Z}}
  ab=0\ \hbox{in}\ \Z_m\quad
  &\Rightarrow\quad m\mid ab\ \hbox{in}\ \Z\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad m\mid a\ \hbox{or}\ m\mid b\ \hbox{in}\ \Z\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad a=0\ \hbox{or}\ b=0\ \hbox{in}\ \Z_m\ .\cr}$$
So $\Z_m$ has no zero divisors.

Conversely, suppose $m$ is composite.  Then $m=ab$ for some $a,b$ with $1\le a,b\le m-1$; so in $\Z_m$ we have $ab=0$ but neither $a=0$ nor $b=0$.  Thus $\Z_m$ contains zero divisors.

Comment: What does m | ab in Z mean?

Comment: "$m\mid ab$" means that $m$ is a factor of $ab$; "in $\Z$" means that we are thinking of $a$ and $b$ as ordinary integers, not as elements of $\Z_m$.